# Unable to download file via Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

*Node.js v10.15.2, googleapis v40.0.0*

I tried this

```
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`/Users/user/Downloads/${fileId}.mp4`);
  drive.files.get({
    fileId,
    alt: 'media'
  },
  {
    responseType: 'stream'
  }, (err, res) => {
    res.data.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Done downloading file!');
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(dest);
  });
```

And got error

```
$ node .
Files:
20140810_125633.mp4 (1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE)
Getting started (0B3K2QXOGSOFRc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl)
(node:62335) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at drive.files.get (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/index.js:104:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:62335) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:62335) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:62335) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at drive.files.get (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/index.js:104:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:62335) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Also, I tried [this example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) from Google API reference.

```
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`/Users/user/Downloads/${fileId}.mp4`);
    drive.files.get({
      fileId,
      alt: 'media'
    })
      .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
      })
      .pipe(dest);
```

And got error

```
$ node .
Files:
20140810_125633.mp4 (1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE)
(node:62336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: drive.files.get(...).on is not a function
    at downloadFile1 (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/index.js:118:8)
    at files.map (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/index.js:87:9)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at drive.files.list (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/index.js:84:13)
    at createAPIRequestAsync.then.r (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:48:53)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:62336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:62336) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:62336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The user has not granted the app 619229308650 read access to the file 1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/user/Development/app/google_drive_integration/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:62336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

I list file 20140810_125633.mp4 successfully but can't download it. What am I doing wrong?

All the code I have

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    pageSize: 1000,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
        downloadFile0(drive, file.id);
        downloadFile1(drive, file.id);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}

function downloadFile0(drive, fileId) {
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`/Users/user/Downloads/${fileId}.mp4`);
  drive.files.get({
    fileId,
    alt: 'media'
  },
  {
    responseType: 'stream'
  }, (err, res) => {
    res.data.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Done downloading file!');
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(dest);
  });
}

function downloadFile1(drive, fileId) {
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`/Users/user/Downloads/${fileId}.mp4`);
    drive.files.get({
      fileId,
      alt: 'media'
    })
      .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
      })
      .pipe(dest);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In API v3 you get a promise from "drive.files.get" and on the promise resolve you have the "data" stream

```
function downloadFile(drive, fileId, fileName) {
  const filePath = `/Users/user/Downloads/${fileName}`;
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  let progress = 0;

  drive.files.get(
    { fileId, alt: 'media' },
    { responseType: 'stream' }
  ).then(res => {
    res.data
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Done downloading file.');
      })  
      .on('error', err => {
        console.error('Error downloading file.');
      })  
      .on('data', d => {
        progress += d.length;
        if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
          process.stdout.clearLine();
          process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
          process.stdout.write(`Downloaded ${progress} bytes`);
        }   
      })  
      .pipe(dest);
  }); 
}
```

Comment: This solution works great to fix the problem I was having with the official google documentation example (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads).  Upvoted. Thx for solving and posting.

Comment: nobody tells how to properly instantiate `drive`

Comment: @LeonardoRick `const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });` Adding this line will instantiate `drive`. You can then pass on this object to the function.