# Send PDF from Server to Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to get access to a pdf from a Google Drive. Whether this access is downloading or viewing, it doesn't really matter, it just needs to be available.

I am using Javascript and NodeJS, with express and google drive api.

I have the following function below which downloads a pdf. But silly me thought this was correct because it worked locally. Then when I deployed it I realised the target filepath no longer makes sense.

```
function downloadDoc (sourceID, targetName, callback) {
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`${os.homedir()}/downloads/`+targetName);
  drive.files.get(
    {sourceID, alt: 'media'},
    {responseType: 'stream'},
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      res.data.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Done downloading file.');
        callback();
      })
       .on('error', err => {
          console.error('Error downloading file.');
          throw err;
        })
        .pipe(dest);
    });
}
```

So what I need to do, is take the data (or response?) from this function and send it over to client side. I assume this is simple to do but, being a simple man, I find myself stuck. I have written this, with the intention that a user can click a link on client side, requesting this URL and calling the function to download the pdf.

```
app.get('/download_pdf', (req, res) => {
    downloadDoc(documentID, 'docName.pdf', ()=>{ 
      console.log("downloaded pdf");
    });
    res.end();
});
```

I'm thinking I need to change the argument provided to pipe() since obviously I can't use the filepath.

Similar questions I've checked: 
[Display Pdf in browser using express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598274/display-pdf-in-browser-using-express-js)

[How to send a pdf file from Node/Express app to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105846/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-from-node-express-app-to-the-browser)

[Send pdf via express to js client and download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285771/send-pdf-via-express-to-js-client-and-download)

While these questions are very related to this, I think my issue is due to a lack of understanding of callbacks or requests/responses. I want to learn this properly - not just ask for answers - but as it is, I'm becoming very pressed for time and need a solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply pipe the returned readable stream to the express `res` object (which is a writeable stream):

```
app.get('/download_pdf', (req, res) => {
    drive.files.get({
        fileId: "your-file-id-here",
        alt: 'media'
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(res);    
});
```

Edit:

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715837/unable-to-download-file-via-google-drive-api/56724621), `drive.files.get` does return a promise. So you need to change it to:

```
app.get('/download_pdf', (req, res) => {
    drive.files.get({
        fileId,
        alt: 'media'
    }, {
        responseType: 'stream'
    }).then(response => {
        response.data
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Done');
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error during download', err);
        })
        .pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried this and get problems with the documentID. If I provide the ID directly as a string then I get a syntax error: Unexpected token ',' 
If I pass it a variable containing the ID then it runs but says 'missing required parameters: fileId'

Comment: e.g. 
drive.files.get({'xfg3H32randomStringKdCt4X', alt: 'media'}, {responseType: etc etc....}

Comment: Just pass it the way you did before through `sourceID`, I edited the answer.

Comment: I still get this error...
(node:10008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing required parameters: fileId

If I change the name of it to fileId, for some reason it passes that error, but gives a new one saying that driveStream.pipe is not a function

Comment: Then you should have seen this error before as well :) Try replacing `sourceID` with `fileId`. See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#javascript

Comment: thanks, I have replaced it with fileId but now I get:  

'TypeError: driveStream.pipe is not a function'

   Thanks for your help, I will continue to look into this

Comment: Maybe check this also: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1971

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the example from that link to work either - it just times out. It also looks like they are saving the pdf on the server end. I need to pass it to the client side.

Comment: I've update my code once more, can you give it another shot? Seems like you need to pipe it directly without awaiting it first.

Comment: Sorry but no, I am still receiving an error. Now, it is:        

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: drive.files.get(...).on is not a function.


I'm leaving the office now, but I appreciate your help. I will have another go tomorrow.

Comment: Weird, sorry I couldn't be of more help. Hopefully you figure it out tomorrow :)

Comment: So I solved it by making a very slight change to the code you provided. I tried to edit your answer to add this but the edit queue is full apparently. If you change it at some point I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to hear that - totally missed that, good catch :) I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way. I'm not sure if this is bad practice but it seems to work. I distinguished between the two response objects by referring to one as response and one as res.

```
app.get('/download_pdf', (req, res) => {
    const docId = req.query.id;
    drive.files.get({
        fileId: docId,
        alt: 'media'
    }, {
        responseType: 'stream'
    }).then(response => {
        response.data
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Done');
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error during download', err);
        })
        .pipe(res);
    });

});
```

Posting this in the event that somebody else has a similar issue.